# Convert a LINQ query to LINQ extensions

Tags: c#, sql, linq

I want to convert my LINQ into LINQ extension methods. Here my code:

```
var fullLastHb = from hb in buklinq.DeviceHeartbeat
                 join hb2 in lastHbTime
                 on new { hb.IdDevice, hb.Timestamp } equals new { hb2.IdDevice, hb2.Timestamp }
                 select hb;
```

thank you in advance

Comment: example: var fullLastHb = buklinq.DeviceHeartbeat.Join(lastHbTime, ......

Comment: https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/

Comment: Offtopic; it'd be more idiomatic to say you want to go from _query syntax_ (`from a in b select a`) to _method syntax_ (`b.Select(a => a)`).

Comment: Resharper, right click -> convert to linq chain method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's straight forward:

```
var fullLastHb = buklinq.DeviceHeartbeat.Join(lastHbTime,
                       hb => ew { hb.IdDevice, hb.Timestamp },
                       hb2 => new { hb2.IdDevice, hb2.Timestamp },
                       (hb, hb2) => hb);
```

You can always translate it like that:

```
from x in source1
join y in source2
on selector1 equals selector2
select projection
```

to

```
source1.Join(source2, x => selector1, y => selector2, (x,y) => projection);
```

or

```
source1.Join(source2, x => selector1, y => selector2, (x,y) => new {x, y})
       .Select(z => projection);
```

---

A very good explanation of how *query syntax* is translated to *method syntax* has been given by [Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work/)